# Scilab Storing Into Array [Channel Coding]

Tags: matlab, scilab

This is part of my codes

```
e=0;
c=0;
n=10000;

for t=zeros(1:n)
//state1
x=rand();
if(x<=0.95) then disp(t);
    c=c+1;
elseif(x>0.95)
//state2
x=rand();
if(x<=0.99) then disp(t)
    c=c+1;
//state3
elseif(x>0.99) then disp(t=1)
    e=e+1;
    arr(e)=t; //store error bits only



end
end
end
disp(c);
disp(e);
for z=1:e //loop the earlier arr(s)
disp(arr(z)) //display all arr of s
end

clear();
```

What I was trying to do is to generate 10000 of zeros.
Out of these 10000 zeros, there will be few with errors meaning to say for example I might get 9990 of zeros and 10 of ones.

Currently, I have made an array storing only the ones. Now I'm abit lost on how do I store both zeros and ones into the same array.

Let say, current running..I will end up with 10 of ones (Those zeros that contains error bit). Then at this part of the code, all the zeros that has turned into ones will be stored into arr(e). Therefore the output would be

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

But what i wanted is something like this.

```
arr[1] = 0
.
.
.
arr[250] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[749] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[1234] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[5463] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[6678] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[8890] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[9987] = 1 
.
.
.
arr[10000] = 0
```

Which shows the error bit occur at 250,749,1234,5463,6678,8890,9987

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

```
e = [250 759 1234 5463 6678 8890 9987];
arr = zeros(10000,1);
arr(e) = 1;
```

`e` defines where you want the values in `arr` to be changed to 1.  You simply just use `e` to index into `arr` and set the corresponding positions to 1.  That's it... nothing really to it!

Comment: But the array at 250,749,1234,5463,6678,8890,9987 is just a random location..next time when i run again the code..the array location could be different

Comment: Well... make sure those locations are stored in `e`.... then do the above code.  You said that you have the locations and they're stored in `e`.... so.... use `e` and index into `arr`. However you're generating the locations, make sure they're stored in `e`. How much simpler do you want me to explain it?